# Domain name to a page

Tags: urls, subdomains, domain

I have a wordpress single blog located in a server.

Say the server address is `http://100.100.100.100`, and my wordpress single blog can be accessed via `http://100.100.100.100/mysite`.

I've mapped this IP address to a domain name `www.example.com`, and I can access the front page of the site via `http://www.example.com`.

However, I need to have a URL to a wordpress page other than the front page, like `http://100.100.100.100/mysite/other-page`.

I can access this other page via `http://100.100.100.100/mysite/other-page`, but I cannot access it via `http://www.example.com/other-page`.

How do I link a URL to a page in wordpress?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add these values in your `wp-config.php`

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://www.example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://www.example.com' );
```

These will overwrite your database values with above. This is a temporary fix.

But to fix this issue permanently. You will have to change URLs in database. You can run these mysql queries to change your URLs from `http://100.100.100.100` to `http://www.example.com`

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://100.100.100.100', 'http://www.example.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://100.100.100.100','http://www.example.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://100.100.100.100', 'http://www.example.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://100.100.100.100','http://www.example.com');
```

One you are done with these queries then you can remove `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` from `wp-config.php` file.

This should fix it.

**Note:** make sure you change domain example URLs with your actual URLs before you start.

Comment: Generally speaking changing the GUID is not great advice because people copy paste answers like this^ and things start to break and then then wonder why.

Comment: What can we do? He supplied example URLs, but I also mentioned that use code to change URL from `http://100.100.100.100` to `http://www.example.com`. Edited and added a note too.

Comment: The GUID is a unique identifier it doesn't have anything to do with the site URL, it should have been a unique key instead, but WP chose to use the domain name as the key. So anyone copy pasting your code the part `UPDATE wp_posts SET guid` will break RSS feeds because readers will think all the content is new.